# How to include PoisonError in my own error type

Tags: rust

(English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.)
In my project thers is an error type:

```
pub type RvzResult<T> = Result<T, RvzError>;
#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum RvzError {
    // some error types...
    ,
    OtherErr(Box<dyn Error>)
}
```

One day I had a `Mutex` object  and used it like this:

```
pub fn some_func() -> RvzResult<()> {
    // ...
    let lock = the_mutex.lock()?;
    // ...
}
```

But rustc wasn't so happy:`error[E0277]: '?' couldn't convert the error to 'RvzError'`
I tried to impl `From` trait like this:

```
impl <T> From<PoisonError<T>> for RvzError {
    fn from(err: PoisonError<T>) -> Self {
        Self::OtherErr(Box::new(err))
    }
}
```

It failed:`error[E0310]: the parameter type 'T' may not live long enough`

Comment: are you using `thiserror`?

Comment: @Netwave yes, I am.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `PoisonError` is *not just an error code,* but has a special function: it allows you to bypass the lock-poisoning check and access the data anyway. The `<T>` parameter of PoisonError is the lock guard object that it [can be asked to return](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.PoisonError.html#method.get_ref), so the `PoisonError` in your function is a borrow of `the_mutex`.

Therefore, it cannot be made into a `Box<dyn Error>` (which is implicitly `+ 'static`) and should not be returned from `some_func()` anyway. Instead, create a new error which *doesn't* try to contain the original `PoisonError` value — either a variant of `RvzError`:

```rust
impl<T> From<PoisonError<T>> for RvzError {
    fn from(err: PoisonError<T>) -> Self {
        Self::Poison
    }
}
```

Or a boxed string error (using [this impl](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3C%26%27_%20str%3E-2)):

```rust
impl<T> From<PoisonError<T>> for RvzError {
    fn from(_: PoisonError<T>) -> Self {
        Self::OtherErr(Box::<dyn Error>::from("PoisonError"))
    }
}
```